# Does the word "teacher" sound childish at university?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, connotation, academia

There is a distinction between the way students refer to teachers in high school and at university in my country and the former way sounds very childish. So, I was just wondering if it is the same in English, particularly in British English. Do you think referring to a teacher at university as *teacher,* rather than *professor,* or *sir,* or something else, sounds childish?

Comment: Teach in Latin languages comes from the idea of pointing at stuff, whereas to profess is another kettle of fish altogether. That said, one can say that professors teach at universities. The verb works, not the noun.

Answer (score 1):

They're usually called **lecturers** or **professors**, in the UK and US at least (@DanBron has pointed out that 'lecturers' may just be used in the UK).  I think that many more staff, as a proportion of the teaching staff, are likely to be called **professors** in the US.

"teacher" doesn't (in my opinion) sound childish, it just sounds wrong.  Technically they teach, so could be called teachers, but that isn't the convention.

Comment: I agree that *teacher* is wrong but it is *also* childish, as In the kind of mistake a student who hasn’t quite left secondary school behind would make. The one who has a certain immature mental model. The undergraduate analog to a 3rd grader calling his teacher *mom*.  Also I don’t think I’ve seen the title *Lecturer* used in the US. Definitely in the UK, but then I believe they have *Readers* and such too.

Comment: @DanBron calling it "childish" is too harsh, I think.  It's not comparable to calling a school teacher "mom", as the teacher is not the child's mother, whereas the university lecturer is actually a teacher, it's just not traditional to **address** them like that.  So in the first instance it's a total error, in the second instance it's just an unawareness of tradition when using a word which is technically accurate.

Comment: Much of this is going to depend on the particular institution's culture. I work at a *teaching* institution in the US, and while "professor" or "instructor" is most common, "teacher" doesn't sound wrong to me. Indeed, most of us consider ourselves (and call ourselves) teachers, first and foremost (even though we are also researchers, and our official title will never include "teacher"). I don't profess at the college, I teach at the college. (Though I have heard of old-school faculty members at R-1 schools who say the opposite.)

Comment: @DanBron I've heard _lecturer_ in use at US universities, but I think it may have a different implication than at British universities. Here is an example: http://www.cs.umd.edu/people/faculty In addition to _Lecturers,_ there are also _Senior Lecturers_ and a _Principal Lecturer._

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I made a quick research on this and I found "doctor 'second name' " is also used. Do you think calling a professor, say, doctor smith, sounds awkward?

Comment: @MikeHarris The difference is that *professor* and *lecturer* are distinct jobs in the U.S., and do not represent academic ranks. This is not unlike the difference between the commander who is captain of a submarine in the U.S. Navy, and the captain who is commander of a U.S. Army company.

Comment: @choster Oftentimes, though, in US universities, a *lecturer* is someone who gives lecture, or holds a lab session, who is not part of the current tenured faculty, such as a visiting professor, a graduate student lecturing an undergrad, freshman-level class, or so on. These people might be referred to altogether as *adjunct faculty*